# How to get the ID of dragged element using NestedSoting plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using JQuery nestedSorting plugin
I can drag and drop multiple elements, How can I get the id of the dragged element ?

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

$('.sortable').nestedSortable({
    handle: 'div',
    items: 'li',
    toleranceElement: '> div'
});

});
</script>
```

**Edit**

I edited the jquery function like this

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var movedItemId = '';
    $('.sortable').nestedSortable({
        handle: 'div',
        items: 'li',
        toleranceElement: 'div',
    }).on("sort", function(a, item){
        movedItemId = '';
        $('div', item.item).each(function(){
            movedItemId += ' ' + $(this).attr('id') + ',';
        });
        var id = movedItemId.substr(0, movedItemId.length - 1);
        var data = {pid:id};
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            url:"{{ path('v2_pm_patents_trashpatents') }}",
            cache: false,
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Problems I face

1. It calls the method I want to execute with Ajax but it call it so many times I want to execute the method only once.
2. When I drag the an item which contains sub items I only want the id of the parent item not the ids of the sub items,

How can I fix these problems?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of limitations with the [nestedSortable](http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable/) plugin.

It's main methods are `.serialize`, `.toArray` or `.toHierarchy` to get the value as a whole.

The plugin uses jQuery Sortable UI. I looked at its event callbacks. I tried the `on("change", [...])` but that doesn't seem to work. The `on("sort", [...])` does work but is called every time the mouse is moved. Have a look at the different event under the Events tab: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

Here's a working version binded to the `sort` callback: http://jsfiddle.net/QL8Yj/4/

Comment: I spend so much time on it :(

Comment: Does not the serialize object contain the id of the dragged element?

Comment: Oh wait. I just looked at the source code. Let me experiment. Will get back to you soon.

Comment: You will save my life If u help me out in this problem

Comment: when I sort items i cant see any id , actually i want to get id when i move any item

Comment: I update the jsfiddle link in my answer above. This should be use as a general guidance and adapted to your exact needs.

Comment: Thanks for the help but can I store this id in a variable and send it to an ajax function once the item is dragged?

Comment: Kindly check my edit, hope u will help me. waiting for ur reply

Comment: I suggest posting the edit as a new question. The question mostly change from "How to get the ids" to "How to submit ids from nestedSortable via AJAX". That way I'm sure you'll get more responses.